# Как в ComboBox (WPF) разрешить копировать текст из него в буфер?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ComboBox, описанный вот так:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDatabaseItem}" Margin="0 3">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Все работает, но текст из самого ComboBox после выбора пункта из списка невозможно выделить и скопировать. Как добиться этого эффекта при сохранении запрета на ручной ввод текста в ComboBox? Спасибо!

Comment: А вы уверены, что никаких свойств влияющих не наложено на элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Комбинация свойств `IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True"` дает именно такой эффект, какой вам нужен.

Да, кстати, если вы хотите отображать в элементах просто значение текстового свойства, то `ItemTemplate` переопределять необходимости нет, можно использовать `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
          IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Comment: Аа, у него комбобокс.. я почему-то был уверен, что текстбокс :/